# Clojure destructure map using :keys with qualified keywords not working

Tags: clojure

I've tried this with both 1.7.0 and 1.8.0 and it appears that Clojure does not destructure maps using `:keys` whose keys are fully qualified. I don't think it has to do with being in the tail on the arguments as it doesn't work when I switch around the function argument positions as well.

```
(ns foo.sandbox)

(def foo ::foo)
(def bar ::bar)

(defn normalize-vals
  [mmap & [{:keys [foo bar] :as ops}]]
  (println "normalize-vals " ops " and foo " foo " bar" bar))

(normalize-vals {} {foo 1 bar 2})

=> normalize-vals  {:foo.sandbox/foo 1, :foo.sandbox/bar 2}  and foo  nil  bar  nil
```

However; this works:

```
    (defn normalize-vals
      [mmap & [{a foo b bar :as ops}]]
      (println "normalize-vals " ops " and foo " a " bar" b))

    (normalize-vals {} {foo 1 bar 2})

=> normalize-vals  {:cmt.sandbox/foo 1, :cmt.sandbox/bar 2}  and foo  1  bar  2
```

Is this a defect?

Comment: FWIW, the Clojure 1.9 beta has additional support for maps with qualified keys: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/UEtE1K9C7XE/5p5BJe2tAQAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are destructuring using unqualified keywords, so instead of:

`[mmap & [{:keys [foo bar] :as ops}]]`

you should use

`[mmap & [{:keys [::foo ::bar] :as ops}]]`

You can use `clojure.walk/macroexpand-all` to expand `normalize-vals`:

```
(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(defn normalize-vals
                                 [mmap & [{:keys [foo bar] :as ops}]]
                                 (println "normalize-vals " ops " and foo " foo " bar" bar)))

=> (def normalize-vals (fn* ([mmap & p__26720] (let* [vec__26721 p__26720 map__26722 (clojure.core/nth vec__26721 0 nil) map__26722 (if (clojure.core/seq? map__26722) (. clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap create (clojure.core/seq map__26722)) map__26722) ops map__26722 foo (clojure.core/get map__26722 :foo) bar (clojure.core/get map__26722 :bar)] (println "normalize-vals " ops " and foo " foo " bar" bar)))))
```

The important part of the expansion to note is:

```
foo (clojure.core/get map__26722 :foo) 
bar (clojure.core/get map__26722 :bar)
```

The keys in the map destructuring are therefore converted to keywords at **compile time** and the values from the foo and bar vars in the namespace will not be used.

Comment: foo and bar are qualified in their definition (`def`)?

Comment: @FrankC. Destructuring will create new local bindings shadowing the foo and bar qualified keyword vars.

Comment: The second condition works (i.e. without ':keys`) so I interpret this as :keys does the local binding which overrides the definition, yes?

Comment: @FrankC. Yes, keys destructuring is expanded into a let form that converts the keys into keywords and looks them up in the map at **compile time** and does not use runtime values of the keys to look the values up in the map, I will update my answer with some details.

Comment: Thank you, checked as answered!

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your function as is:

```
(defn normalize-vals
  [mmap & [{:keys [foo bar] :as ops}]]
  (println "normalize-vals " ops " and foo " foo " bar" bar))
```

Note that `foo` & `bar` above are local bindings, they do not refer to anything outside of the function.

...and rewrite the other bits of code a bit:

```
(def foo-const ::foo)
(def bar-const ::bar)
```

Don't pay too much attention to the naming here, the point is to use different names.

```
(normalize-vals {} {foo 1 bar 2})
;; error: ...Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context...

(normalize-vals {} {foo-const 1 bar-const 2})
;; prints: normalize-vals  {:user/foo 1, :user/bar 2}  and foo  nil  bar nil
```

The lesson should be to use unique names as much as possible.

---

#### Why did the 2nd variant work?

In the destructuring form `{a foo b bar :as ops}`;

- `a` & `b` are new local bindings. If we had a var named `a` or `b` these would override them within the scope of this function.
- `foo` & `bar` are resolved from the environment. If we don't suffix them with `-const` as above we would get a `CompilerException` just like the one above.